# "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature" in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-final-form, final-form

I've got a React-Final-Form which I want it typed with it's own types. 
But `children(renderRest)' is giving the following error:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type
>   'string | number | true | {} | ReactElement ReactElement
>   Component)> | null) | (new (props: any) =>
>   Component)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal | ((props:
>   FormRenderProps) => ReactNode)' has no compatible call
>   signatures.ts(2349)

And my code is:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Form as StateForm, FormProps } from "react-final-form";

import Box from "src/App/Components/Layout/Box";

const StyledForm = styled(Box)``;

const Form = ({ children, ...rest }: FormProps) => {
  return (
    <StateForm
      {...rest}
      render={({ handleSubmit, ...renderRest }) => (
        <StyledForm as="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {children && children(renderRest)}
        </StyledForm>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default React.memo(Form);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This error "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature" has happened in various situations which I was able to solve. But not on this case unfortunately.

Any hints please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the type definitions for `react-final-form` it defines `children` in `RenderableProps` (which `FormProps` extends) as:

```
export interface RenderableProps<T> {
  children?: ((props: T) => React.ReactNode) | React.ReactNode;
  component?: React.ComponentType<T> | string;
  render?: (props: T) => React.ReactNode;
}
```

So `children` is either a function that takes in `props` and creates a `React.ReactNode` or it is a `React.ReactNode` instance directly.  In the latter case you can't use it like a function.  Since it could be either TS will only let you do the things that are in common between the two.  The error `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.` is basically saying, "You are trying to use `children` like it is a function and that isn't allowed because I don't know for sure it is a function."

I don't know the `react-final-form` library well enough to say the best way to fix this.  You could cast...

```
(children as ((props: T) => React.ReactNode))(renderRest);
```

...or you could add a type guard...

```
if (typeof children === 'function') {
  children(renderRest);
}
```